# creating directives that have common functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just looking for some advice and how to create a number of directives that have similar 
functionality,but differ on there template and data.

So for example you can think of what I have as 3*4 cards, and each card can have a different
template. So you might have a personal card, business card, report card etc. All these cards will appear together in an unordered list. They have similar functional such that they can be clicked, edited, published,deleted.

At the moment I have a directive for each card type and then just using and ng-if when looping through the records and checking the card.type to see which directive to load. This doesn't feel right to me, since there could be up to 20 different cards

```
app.directive('myFitnessCard',[function(){
return {
    restrict : 'EA',
    replace : true,
    template : '<div>Calories : {{ entry.calories }}</div>',
    scope : {
        'entry' :'=?',
        'click' : '&',
        'togglePublish' : '&'
    },
    link : function(scope,elem,attrs){
        scope.$watch('entry.public', function(newVal,oldVal){
            scope.is_published = newVal;
        });

        scope.publish = function(e){
            scope.togglePublish({'entry' : scope.entry});
        };

        elem.bind('click', function(e){
            scope.click({ "entry" : scope.entry });
        });
    }
};
}]);




app.directive('myReportCard',[function(){
return{
    restrict : 'EA',
    replace : true,
    template : '<div>Completed : {{ entry.tasks_completed }}</div>',
    scope : {
        'entry' : '=?'
    },
    link : function(scope,elem,attrs){
        scope.$watch('entry.public', function(newVal,oldVal){
            scope.is_published = newVal;
        });

        scope.publish = function(e){
            scope.togglePublish({'entry' : scope.entry});
        };

        elem.bind('click', function(e){
            scope.click({ "entry" : scope.entry });
        });
    }

};
}]);



<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="e in entries">
        <div ng-if="e.type === 'report'" my-report-card entry="e"></div>
        <div ng-if="e.type === 'fitness'" my-fitness-card entry="e"></div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Here's a very simple version of what I'm trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/pVgY2/

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Please post a Plunker or JSFiddle with the code you have so far so we can give you better suggestions than very abstract answers about refactoring and reusable structures.

Comment: Will each directive really have _similar_ functionality or will it actually be the _same_?

Comment: They will basically be the same and only differ by the template being rendered